# Rails app cannot handle multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, sqlite, passenger

I've got a rails application deployed to a server. RHEL 6.1, ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0.9. EC2 micro instance, 590MB ram (that seems weird, but whatever).

It's currently running in development mode with sqlite3, though I've had it in production and connected to postgresql. The problem has persisted the entire time.

Basically, it runs fine locally, and it runs OK when I'm the only one using it. I'm able to load up a bunch of tabs from the site, without too much of a performance hit. I'm not sure if I'm not just taxing it enough, but it seems like as soon as a second user attempts to use the site, it slows down and crashes. I know the memory is low on this system, but is Rails really that taxing?

About 4-6 ruby processes will spawn when using the app, using up to ~18% of memory each. They tend to persist for several minutes.

Please take a look at my apache log. Please ignore the ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid lines. That's an unrelated issue: http://project.touchstudios.net/error_log.txt

I'm not sure if it's a problem in my application, or the configuration. This has been a very frustrating problem. Can somebody suggest a course of action for me here? I'll provide any information that might help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it tends to be something simple. Something about this site, but I tend to answer my own question pretty quickly after asking it.

EC2 micro instances just don't seem to be very good. I guess there's just a certain amount of overhead. I've fired up a large instance, and the ruby processes don't seem to be growing uncontrollably. I was reluctant to just throw more hardware at the problem; didn't want to cover up a deeper problem, but I'm now led to believe that the micro instances just don't cut it for a medium-size rails app.